# Finding median for a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, median

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with PDF
>
> $$f_X(x)=
> \begin{cases} cx(1-x), 
>  & \text{$0<x<1$} \\ 0, 
> & \text{elsewhere} 
> \end{cases}$$
> Find the median of $X$.

My question is how I am only given PDF, to calculate median, do I need to find CDF for it? And how?

Comment: Note that distribution is not uniform.

Comment: @herbsteinberg fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get CDF $F_X(1)=1=c\int_0^1x(1-x)dx =\frac{c}{6}$, so $c=6$

Next $F_X(x)=6\int_0^xu(1-u)du=3x^2-2x^3$.

To get median $3x^2-2x^3=\frac{1}{2}$ and solve for $x$ in the interval $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to calculate anything.

The distribution is symmetric about $x=\frac 12$. (Draw it.)

So, median and mean are the same and are equal to $\frac 12$.